# Why are $\frac{3x^2-3}{2x} = 0$ and $3x^2-2x-3 = 0$ not equivalent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Why are these equations not equivalent?
$$\frac{3x^2-3}{2x} = 0 \qquad\qquad 3x^2-2x-3 = 0$$

The equations have different roots.

Roots of $3x^2-2x-3 = 0$:
$$x =\frac{1\mp \sqrt{10}}{3}$$

Roots $\frac{3x^2-3}{2x} = 0$:
$$\pm 1$$

Comment: I’m sorry, why would they be equal?

Comment: $\frac{3x^2-3}{2x} = 1$  would work  the way you seem to think

Comment: @WillJagy why???

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts $1\times2x=2x\neq0=0\times2x$, if you factor the numerator of the fraction, and the polynomial of the other equation, they have different zeroes and different roots.

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts You still haven't explained how you went from $\,\frac{a}{b} = 0\,$ to $\,a-b = 0\,$.

Comment: @dxiv thats my question

Comment: your question is why isn’t $\frac{a}{b}=0$ the same as $a-b=0$? Why on earth would those be equal? Subtraction and division are simply different operations.

Comment: multiplying $b$ on both sides leads to $a=b\cdot0=0$. You seem to be confusing multiplying by $1$ and multiplying by $0$

Comment: @Malady thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the fraction as follows:

$$
\frac{3x^2-3}{2x} = \frac{3x^2}{2x} - \frac{3}{2x} = \frac{3}{2}x- \frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{x}
$$
which is not the same as the second equation